# I can't get SwiftMailer to send in a Symfony2 Command

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I'm trying to setup a Command to send out warning emails, but I can't get SwiftMailer to actually send them.

I read some posts about flushing the Spooler but I am still not seeing emails going to Postfix.

The emails do work in a controller, and I receive them. So I know that Postfix itself is working, and that SwiftMailer works from a Controller.

This is the execute function I have

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $container = $this->getContainer();
    $entityManager = $container->get('doctrine')->getManager();
    $mailer = $container->get('mailer');
    $transport = $container->get('swiftmailer.transport.real');


    $things = $container->get('mike.stuff.service')->getThings();
    foreach ($things as $thing) {

            $recipients = array($thing->getPerson()->getEmail() => $thing->getPerson()->getName());

            $message = sprintf('Hello %s'.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL.'This is an alert regarding %s',
                    $thing->getPerson()->getName(),
                    $thing->getReferenceNumber());

            $email = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                ->setSubject('Alert')
                ->setFrom('noreply@mydomain.com')
                ->setTo($recipients)
                ->setBody($message);
            $mailer->send($email);
        }
    }

    // Flush the mailer transport
    $spool = $mailer->getTransport()->getSpool();
    $sent = $spool->flushQueue($transport);

    echo 'I sent ' . $sent;
}
```

When I run the command the output is "I sent 1", so it looks like it has worked. But /var/log/mail.log does not have anything added to it (so of course I don't receive an email).

Comment: Do you have a different configuration for email in dev and prod environments? Commands are run on the dev environment by default, so if you have different configs, you may need to run your command in the prod environment (with `--env=prod`)

Comment: Perfect thanks. My environments are setup slightly differently, but this is the cause of my problem.

Comment: i added my comment as an answer so that you may accept it. This may help other users with a similar problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commands are run in the `dev` environment by default, so if you have different configs for `dev` and `prod` environments, you will need to run your command in the `prod` environment (with `--env=prod`)